# Topic subscription for events between classes in Android

Tags: android, event-handling, publish-subscribe

I'm wondering if exists an Android service (or a library internal or not) similar the iOs's Grand Central Dispacher (in Java could be JMS-Topic): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

Basically in **class A** I want to register itself to a Topic and defining an handler method like this:

```
class A extends HandlerClass {

 public A () {
 MyCustomGrandCentralDispacth.addListenerToTopic("myImportantEvent", this)
 }

 @Override
 void myHandlerMethod(Object data) {
   //do somenthing
 }
 ...
}
```

In another class I want to call

```
MyCustomGrandCentralDispacth.notifyEvent("myImportantEvent", data);
```

so this will trigger the myHandlerMethod.

Any suggestions?

Obviously there will be many classes registered to this topic.
I'm just asking in order to avoid to rewrite something there is yet available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Android, we call them event buses. See `LocalBroadcastManager` and greenrobot's EventBus. The primary difference compared to your code is that the "topics" are Java classes representing events, not strings.

Comment: many thanks @CommonsWare